# Retain values from top rows

Tags: sas, retain

I have a table with three fields: Fruit, Color and Grade. For all fruits, the grade is 1.

The question I have is:

For all the entries having grade 1, I want to retain the first color from the top row. But if the same kind of fruit shows twice, then retain the second color of this fruit for the rest of records.

Table 1:

```
Fruit      Color   Grade
------------------------
Apple      Green   1
Apple      Red     1
Cherry     Yellow  1 
Strawberry Yellow  1
```

Ideal Table 2:

```
Fruit      Color   Grade
------------------------
Apple      Green   1
Apple      Red     1
Cherry     Red     1
Strawberry Red     1
```

Can anyone help out?

Thanks lots!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with the use of `retain` or `lag`. I tend to avoid using `lag`, so here's a solution using `retain`.

Note that I didn't take into account the Grade since you specify it's always 1 for fruits, and we wouldn't expect to find any other things than fruits in a column named... fruit!

```
data table1;
  length fruit $ 12 Color $ 12;
  input Fruit Color Grade;
  datalines;
Apple      Green   1
Apple      Red     1
Cherry     Yellow  1
Strawberry Yellow  1
Strawberry Pink    1
Banana     Yellow  1
run;
```

### Using `retain`:

```
data table2(drop=tmp_fruit);
  format tmp_fruit $12. Fruit $12. Color $12. Grade 1.;
  retain tmp_fruit '' Color '' ;
  set table1(rename=(Color=old_color));

  * Initialize values of retained variables;
  if _N_ = 1 then do;
    Color = old_color;
    tmp_fruit = Fruit;
  end;

  * Update tmp_fruit if necessary;
  if Fruit ne tmp_fruit then do;
    tmp_fruit = Fruit;
  end;

  * Modify Color if necessary;
  else if old_color ne Color then do;
    Color = old_color;
  end;
run;
```

### Results

```
Fruit      Color   Grade  old_color 
-----------------------------------
Apple      Green   1      Green 
Apple      Red     1      Red 
Cherry     Red     1      Yellow 
Strawberry Red     1      Yellow 
Strawberry Pink    1      Pink 
Banana     Pink    1      Yellow
```

---

### EDIT

OP asked to take into account possible values of Grade being other than 1.

This will work as long as data are sorted by Grade...

```
data table1;
  length fruit $ 12 Color $ 12;
  input Fruit Color Grade;
  datalines;
Apple      Green   1
Apple      Red     1
Cherry     Yellow  1
Strawberry Yellow  1
Strawberry Pink    1
Banana     Yellow  1
Kiwi       Green   1
Bicycle    Golden  2
Carpet     Brown   2
Doughnut   White   3
run;

data table2(drop=tmp_fruit);
  format tmp_fruit $12. Fruit $12. Color $12. Grade 1.;
  retain tmp_fruit '' Color '';
  set table1(rename=(Color=old_color));

  * Initialize values of retained variables;
  if _N_ = 1 then do;
    Color = old_color;
    tmp_fruit = Fruit;
    tmp_grade = Grade;
  end;

  * Update tmp_fruit if necessary;
  if Fruit NE tmp_fruit and Grade EQ 1 then do;
    tmp_fruit = Fruit;
  end;

  * Modify Color if necessary;
  else if old_color ne Color and Grade EQ 1 then do;
    Color = old_color;
  end;

  * For grades other than 1;
  else Color = old_color;
run;
```

Results:

```
Fruit       Color  Grade old_color 
----------------------------------
Apple       Green  1     Green 
Apple       Red    1     Red 
Cherry      Red    1     Yellow 
Strawberry  Red    1     Yellow 
Strawberry  Pink   1     Pink 
Banana      Pink   1     Yellow 
Kiwi        Pink   1     Green 
Bicycle     Golden 2     Golden 
Carpet      Brown  2     Brown 
Doughnut    White  3     White
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They work well! What if I change to add grade level? For example the last three records, grade changes to 2. What should the code change?

Comment: Thanks. It works very well. Much appreciated for your help.